# Can I scroll to an HTML-element in another component's template?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In one component I have a navbar with a feature to scroll to an element on the page.

Navbar Template:

```
 <a class="nav-link" (click)="scroll(services)">Services</a>
```

Navbar Component

```
scroll(id) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

The element in another component I want to scroll to:

```
<section class="page-section" id="services">
```

The components are unrelated, both are children of app.component.html.

Can this be done, what do I do if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template you need to pass string to method:

Change this:

```html
 <a class="nav-link" (click)="scroll(services)">Services</a>
```

To this:

```html
 <a class="nav-link" (click)="scroll('services')">Services</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't do it with double-quotes, but single-quotes worked!

Comment: Of course, it should be single quotes. I've edited my answer